# excluding joined table data from final results

Tags: sequelize.js

Let's suppose I have the following code:

```
const { Entrada, Entidade } = require('./models');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

let nome = 'dd';

async function main() {

    Entrada.findOne({

        where: {
            ativa: true
        },

        include: [{
            model: Entidade,
            where: {
                nome: {
                    [Op.like]: `%${nome.trim()}%`
                },
                ativa: true
            }
        }]

    }).then(entrada => {

        console.error(
            JSON.stringify(
                entrada, null, 2));

    });
}

main();
```

Witch runs fine and will return me:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "numeroDaNota": "101011011",
  "dataDaNota": "2020-10-01",
  "dataDeEntrada": "2020-10-02",
  "valor": 150,
  "ativa": true,
  "lojaId": 1,
  "entidadeId": 1,
  "entidade": {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "dddd",
    "fantasia": null,
    "documento": "dddd",
    "isentoDeInscricaoEstadual": 1,
    "inscricaoEstadualOuRg": null,
    "tipoDePessoa": "FISICA",
    "situacaoTributaria": "SIMPLES_NACIONAL",
    "email": "dddd",
    "emailNFE": null,
    "ativa": true,
    "foneFixo": null,
    "celular": "8888",
    "logradouro": "ooo",
    "cep": "111",
    "numero": 111,
    "complemento": null,
    "bairro": "111",
    "cliente": true,
    "fornecedor": true,
    "transportadora": false,
    "limiteDeCredito": null,
    "descontoEmVenda": null,
    "observacao": null,
    "suframa": null,
    "cidadeId": 23,
    "empresaId": 1,
    "paisId": 206,
    "atividadeFimId": null,
    "regiaoId": null,
    "figuraFiscalId": null
  }
}
```

However, I am not interested in property "entidade" from the model "Entrada" in my output. I've only joined it (by means of 'include: []') because I needed to filter "Entrada" by a property of "Entidade" (that property being "nome"). I'm aware I can use **toJSON() {}** when defining a model in order not to "jsonning" properties I don't want to, like passwords for instance.

However isn't there a neat way to exclude joined models from the final output by simply using a sequelize parameter while querying? I took a look at:

```
MyModel.findAll({
  attributes: {exclude: ['some_field']}
});
```

And tried to exclude "entidade" from the final JSON, but it seems it will not exclude joined models/tables from the end result. I find this lacking in sequelize. Coming from 17 years of experience with Hibernate, this seems frustrating.

There must be a way to do that, and I must be missing it.

Please, help me if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to indicate an empty array in the `attributes` option of included model:

```js
include: [{
            model: Entidade,
            attributes: [],
            where: {
                nome: {
                    [Op.like]: `%${nome.trim()}%`
                },
                ativa: true
            }
        }]
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing

```
attributes:[]
```

in your code such as

```sh
include: [{
            attributes: [],
            model: Entidade,
            where: {
                nome: {
                    [Op.like]: `%${nome.trim()}%`
                },
                ativa: true
            }
        }]
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks.